# VBS - file not found

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to chceck if my PC does have for example outlook.exe in directory (it does) but when running code FileExists aperently return me false which cases me to show message that file doen't exist. Can you help me?

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

outlook15 = "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office15\outlook.exe"

If (fso.FileExists("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.exe")) Then  
    msgbox outlook15 & " exists."
Else
    msgbox outlook15 & "doesn't exists."    
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` to translate `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` to a proper path.

```
strPath = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles(x86)%")
outlook15 = strPath & "\Microsoft Office\Office15\outlook.exe"

If fso.FileExists(outlook15) Then
    msgbox outlook15 & " exists."
Else
    msgbox outlook15 & " doesn't exist."
End If
```

Comment: ok thank you it worked, but now when it is true try to open Outlook with `WshShell.Run(outlook15)` it sayis that "System cannot find the file specified"

Comment: That's because the `Run()` function needs quotes surrounding any paths that contain spaces. Use `WshShell.Run Chr(34) & outlook15 & Chr(34)` instead.